# Conditionally making a number field required with YUP in React with react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form, yup

I have a form where if a certain radio option is selected I want to render a number input box, which should be required if the radio option is selected.
Here is my YUP schema for the relevant inputs:

```
areSeatsLimited: yup.string().required(),
numOfSeats: yup
      .number()
      .positive("This field must contain a positive number")
      .integer("This field should contain an integer")
      .when("areSeatsLimited", {
        is: "yes",
        then: yup.number().required().typeError("The field must contain a number"),
        otherwise: yup.number().notRequired().typeError("The field must contain a number"),
      }),
```

This works in a sense that if I open the form for the first time and dont choose the option that seats are limited, upon submitting I get no error from the numOfSeats input, which is expected since its not required.

However, if I check the seats are limited, then it gives me the error, which is also expected since its now required. **But here is the problem**: when I check that seats are unlimited again **after** selecting that they are limited. It still throws me the error as if the field is required. Also note its throwing me the typerror message("The field must contain a number")

Here is the react code for that part of the form

```
<div className="radio" style={{ display: "block", marginTop: "10px" }}>
              <input
                value="no"
                type="radio"
                id="unlimited"
                {...register("areSeatsLimited")}
                checked={areSeatsLimited === "no" || areSeatsLimited === undefined ? true : false}
              />
              <label htmlFor="unlimited">Unlimited</label>
            </div>
            <div className="radio" style={{ display: "block", marginTop: "10px" }}>
              <input
                value="yes"
                type="radio"
                id="limited"
                {...register("areSeatsLimited")}
                checked={areSeatsLimited === "yes" ? true : false}
              />
              <label htmlFor="limited">Limited</label>
            </div>
            {areSeatsLimited === "yes" ? (
              <div className={`form-group required ${errors?.numOfSeats?.message ? "has-error" : ""}`}>
                <label htmlFor="numOfSeats">Number Of Seats</label>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  id="numOfSeats"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Amount of available seats..."
                  {...register("numOfSeats")}
                />
                {errors?.numOfSeats?.message ? (
                  <span style={{ color: "var(--input-error-text-color)" }}>{errors.numOfSeats.message}</span>
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}
              </div>
```

I have a similar set of fields but with string, and it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
otherwise: number().transform(() => {
    return undefined;
    }).nullable().notRequired(),
```

An input field, according to this guy [here](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/908#issuecomment-578452753), will return an **empty string** if you don't provide input, that is why it is throwing typeError. So you need to manually force it to return undefined when the seats are unlimited.

Comment: But then it's not validitaing anything at all

Comment: @OleksandrFomin you must be doing something wrong then, as I tested this myself